# Confusion understanding this sentence: Could you speak English before you came here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, auxiliary-verbs

I stumbled upon this one sentence in an EFL book.

> Could you speak English before you came here ?

The whole chapter is dedicated to **can** and **could**.

There are no other sentences around the above one so there is no context I can guess from.

First of all, does this sentence sound natural ?

Second, does it mean

> Were you able to speak English before you came here ?

Or is it some weird way of saying,

Could you do something(in this case, speak English) before you **come** here ?

Answer (score 3):

1) The sentence sounds perfectly fine to me.

2) You are correct, it means "were you able to". (Past tense of can)